# Kotlin: Mock AWS S3 client using Mockito

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, amazon-s3, mockito

I'm trying to mock the S3 client which is built using AmazonS3ClientBuilder. How do I do it?

Here is my code:

```
val s3client: AmazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion(s3BucketRegion)
                .build()
val request: PutObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest(
                s3BucketName,
                "$s3BucketKey/file.json",
                ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayJson),
                metadata
            ).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.BucketOwnerFullControl)

s3client.putObject(request)
```

Here is what I tried, but I keep getting 403 error. This means it is not mocking the client

```
        val mockS3Client = mock(AmazonS3::class.java)
        val mockPutObjectRequest = mock(PutObjectRequest::class.java)
        val mockPutObjectResult = mock(PutObjectResult::class.java)
        //val mockAmazonS3ClientBuilder = mock(AmazonS3ClientBuilder::class.java)

        //whenever(mockAmazonS3ClientBuilder.withRegion("").build()).thenReturn(mockS3Client)
        whenever(mockS3Client.putObject(mockPutObjectRequest)).thenReturn(mockPutObjectResult)
```

Comment: are you using any DI framework, like spring? If yes, create a bean of AmazonS3 and inject it to required class instead of instantiating in the method. Then you can mock the object

Comment: @sidgate Yes, I’m using Spring. Do you have a ref code for this? It would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You need to inject the created mock into your sut (system under test). Otherwise the mock won't be used. But based on your code you are instantiating the s3 client inside the method you use it: `val s3client: AmazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder`. This way you won't be able to inject the mock to your sut. The posted code should get the s3 client injected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the approaches to mock dependencies is by injecting dependent object. You can define a bean of `AmazonS3` in a Spring configuration class

```
@Configuration
class AwsConfig{
  @Bean fun amazonS3() = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion(s3BucketRegion)
                .build()

}
```

And in the dependent class, just inject the object

```
@Service
class MyService(
  private val s3Client: AmazonS3
){
  fun someMethod(){
    val request: PutObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest(
                s3BucketName,
                "$s3BucketKey/file.json",
                ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayJson),
                metadata
            ).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.BucketOwnerFullControl)

    s3client.putObject(request)
  }
}
```

In the test, you would just pass a mock s3 client to `MyService`